# Compare user input to the database

Tags: php, mysqli

I am having a small issue, Where I am trying to check an answer to question in the database,

I am doing a query based on the question ID passed in and pulling the answer setting it as a variable, Then I wanted to compare the variable with the user input; I;m making a silly mistake but cannot figure it out.

**Update #1 :**
Its just showing Error no matter what is entered 
I have also tried comparing them with !=

```
<?php

// establishing the MySQLi connection

require_once('connection-test.php');
$mysqli = new mysqli($host,$username,$password,$database);

    if($mysqli -> connect_error)die($mysqli->connect_error);


$questionID = $_POST['id'];

$dbAnswer = "SELECT answers FROM answers where questionID='$questionID'";

$answer = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli,$_POST['answer']);
if ($result3 = $mysqli->query($dbAnswer)) {

    /* fetch object array */
    while ($obj = $result3->fetch_object()) {
        //printf ("%s  \n", $obj->answers);
        $ans = $obj->answers;

        echo $ans;

    }
    if($ans != $result3){
        echo "<b>error</b>" . $answer;
    }else{
         echo "<br><br><br>";
        echo "Correct" . $answer;
    }

    /* free result set */
    $result3->close();
}

?>
```

Comment: So are you seeing 'error' when you should be seeing 'Correct'? Or is there some other error?

Comment: Sorry I'll update the question, I am getting "Error" no matter what I pass in, I dunno if its not comparing them , I tried to compare them with != but nothing.

Comment: Even ignoring the type juggling probably causing your problems, the condition doesn't make sense anyway.

Comment: You're comparing the answer you're are pulling from the database against $result3 which is '$mysqli->query($dbAnswer)'. I think you want to be comparing this against the $_POST['answer']

Comment: HI Maxxi, I read somewhere that it wouldn't be recommended to compare it against $_POST['answer']  as its less secure and higher change of mysql injection?

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed my issue and now everything is working correctly, Here is the code I used

```
// establishing the MySQLi connection

require_once('connection-test.php');
$mysqli = new mysqli($host,$username,$password,$database);

if($mysqli -> connect_error)die($mysqli->connect_error);


$questionID = $_POST['id'];
$userAnswer = $_POST['answer'];

$query = "SELECT answers FROM answers WHERE questionID=?";
$statement = $mysqli->prepare($query);
$statement ->bind_param('i', $questionID);

$statement->execute();

$statement->bind_result($answer);


while($statement->fetch()){
    if($answer != $userAnswer){
        echo "Wrong";
    }else{
        echo "correct!";
}

}

 $statement->close();
```